# How do I get my housecarl to move with me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just bought the Tundra Homestead, and I'd like Lydia to move in there with me. I got her to follow me into the house, then dismissed her, but she immediately turned around and went back to Breezehome. I think she came to Breezehome automatically when I bought it... I might've entered dialogue with her once I'd bought the house, to see if I could tell her I had a house, but I don't remember.

I'd really prefer to have Lydia in the house with me so that I don't have to go through the Whiterun loading screen, manage to remember where Breezehome is, then go through *that* loading screen to find Lydia.

How can I get Lydia to move into the Tundra Homestead with me?

Answer (score 3):

[Housecarls](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Housecarl) are bound to a location, you can't move them.

However you can [marry](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Marriage_(Skyrim)) them and then move them to whatever house you want. Additionally the homes you build in the Heartfire DLC (and some creation Club items) can be appointed [stewards](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Steward_(Hearthfire)?so=search) that will reside in that house.
[image: Housecarls]

Comment: ...that isn't helpful. I talked to my step-dad a little about it last night and he said you can get your housecarl to move house with you, just like a spouse and kids. Also, I don't think you even CAN marry your housecarl.

Comment: @PhoenixDreaming your step dad is wrong, and you can marry them... it's even shown in the image i posted. you can marry Lydia and as a wife you can have her go to whatever house. Or in some cases you can hire her as a steward.

Comment: Yes. You have already stated this.

Comment: @PhoenixDreaming with the given information and links... what is the remaining problem?

Comment: You. You keep talking to me like I know nothing, and I'm tired of it.

Comment: @PhoenixDreaming you ask a question, i answer it with all the information i can provide... that's how this site works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142032/discussion-between-phoenix-dreaming-and-a-bakker).

Comment: @PhoenixDreaming so is there any other information you require? or is this answer correct?

Comment: *sigh* not correct. I've got Lydia as the steward for Goldenhills Plantation now, so there's that at least. I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: @PhoenixDreaming if you want her at the Tundra homestead your only option is console commands or marrying her... the information given is correct seeing Tundra Homestead is a bought house and not one you can build making her unavailable as a Steward there...

Comment: It may be logically correct, but that doesn't mean it helped me, especially in the way you presented it. *And* how you keep bugging me about it. Please stop, by the way.